# srcdir attributes must be set

Tags: gradle, ant

Im trying to migrate my code from ant to gradle and imported my build.xml in build.gradle and some of my tasks work fine. 
However there are some tasks when i run them it says

Execution failed for task ':compile'.

> srcdir attribute must be set!

Pasting a snippet of my Build.xml and the compile task below is failing.

```
<project basedir="." default="deploy" name="FitNesse"> 
<property name="fitnesse.target" value="/build/test-fitnesse"/> 

<patternset id="test.patternset"> 
<include name="**/*Test*.java"/> 
</patternset> 
<propertyset id="test.propertyset"> 
<propertyref name="basedir"/> 
<propertyref name="test.patternset"/> 
</propertyset> 


<fileset id="classpath.fitnesse" dir="./libs"> 
<include name="antlr-2.7.7.jar"/> 
<include name="asm-4.1.jar"/> 
<include name="asm-analysis-4.1.jar"/> 
<include name="asm-commons-4.1.jar"/> 
<include name="asm-tree-4.1.jar"/ 

><target name="compile" description="Compile java sources" depends="clean"> 
<mkdir dir="build/classes"/> 
<javac includeantruntime="false"/> 
<javac srcdir="src/main/java" destdir="build/classes" debug="on"> 
<classpath refid="classpath.compile"/> 
<compilerarg value="-processorpath"/> 
<compilerarg value="-AmethodConstraintsSupported=true"/> 
</javac> 
</target>
```

Source folder structure 
/src/main/java/com/xebia/inc/xeb

I had changed my src folder structure from ant "src" to a gradle project "/src/main/java/com/xebia/incubator/xebium". and lib folder to libs

Please help. I'm kind of novice to this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The full error message should give you the line number and it's most probably the line that contains

```
<javac includeantruntime="false"/>
```

which looks like a copy-paste error.

Comment: what should be the right tag? (sorry im new this this whole thing :( )

Comment: tried this and i still get the same error.        <javac srcdir="src/main/java" destdir="build/classes" debug="on" includeantruntime="false">

Comment: Please take a look at the task at the reported line number. to ensure you are fixing the right one.